# OWL Api, move class from parent A to B

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I'm having a quick question regarding the usage of the owl api.

Say I have a class called Species, which has a Subclass mammal, which has a Subclass Primate, which has a subclass Human.

species -> mammal -> primate -> human

For some reason, I would like to reclassify this in our software and say that Primates are not longer considered Mammals, instead they should be a direct subclass of a Species.

Meaning our graph should look like this now

species -> primate -> human

can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Finding our the parent class is easy enough, using the owl-api

```
reasoner.getSuperClasses(chield, true).entities().collect(Collectors.toSet[OWLClass])
```

but how can I 'detach' my class now from it's parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an ontology where the relations :

- species -> mammal
- mammal -> primate
- primate -> human

are directly asserted (not the result of a reasoning computation).

Then in owlapi this is represented as axioms :

1. OWLSubClass(mammal, species)
2. OWLSubClass(primate, mammal)
3. OWLSubClass(human, primate)

The solution could be to remove the old subClass assertion and add the new one (unless you are playing with Allen-temporal).

```
OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
ontology.remove(factory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(primate, mammal));
ontology.add(factory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(primate, species));
```

Note : if you are using a version older than 5 of owlapi then we must use the OWLOntologyManager to remove/add axioms in an ontology :

```
manager.remove(ontology, axiom)
manager.add(ontology, axiom)
```

If the specialization relation aren't directly asserted in your ontology; it will be far more complex. You have to know why 'human' is view a subclass of 'mammal'. Maybe the 'explanation' system of the 'reasoner' can help you.

Comment: Not just 'could be' - if the subclass axiom is asserted, it *must* be removed in order to change the hierarchy. If inferred, it is necessary to understand why and remove/counteract the reason for the inference as well.

Comment: thank you very much. Will this also keep all potential sub classes and individuals of human. Or will I have to keep track of them manually?